# Summing Displacements of two Cranks and Sliders

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms, kinematics, linkage

Is there a linkage mechanism allowing the summation of the throws of two crank and slider mechanisms oriented next to one another in order to control an output slider with a motion equal to the summed displacement of the two input crank?

Eg: if slider 1 is positions 5mm above it's equilibrium position at top dead centre and slider 2 is 3mm above it's equilibrium position at just below top dead center I want slider 3 (the output) to be 8mm above it's equilibrium position

[image]

Comment: Please post pictures of your idea. It is extremely difficult for the users to guess what you mean by just giving a brief example.

Comment: @RameezUlHaq I have added an example of what I would like the mechanism to do.

Comment: you can always put the mechanisms in series and then duplicate them. 

Again it is probably useless, because it defeats the objective of putting them next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have three equal diameter hydraulic cylinders connected to a common fluid tank. It, of course is useless, if you expect no interaction between the inputs.